# Windows Core Audio: IsFormatSupported and Initialize are in disagreement over WAVEFORMATEX, but agree on WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE

Tags: windows-core-audio

I am trying to initialize an audio capture client. If I use the following code, `IsFormatSupported` returns `S_OK` and `Initialize` returns `E_INVALIDARG`.

```
WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
wfx.cbSize = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);
wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
wfx.nChannels = 2;
wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16;
wfx.nBlockAlign = wfx.nChannels * wfx.wBitsPerSample / 8;
wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nSamplesPerSec * wfx.nBlockAlign;

WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx = reinterpret_cast<WAVEFORMATEX*>(&wfx);
WAVEFORMATEX* pWfxout = nullptr;

hr = pAudioClient->IsFormatSupported(
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE,
    &wfx,
    &pWfxout
);

assert(hr == S_OK);

hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE,
    0,
    hnsRequestedDuration,
    0,
    pwfx,
    nullptr);

assert(hr == E_INVALIDARG);
```

After struggling with this for a few hours (in addition to a few more trying out a shared mode device, but that's a subject for another post) I vaguely recalled that if you use `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` things are less painful. So I modified the code like this.

```
WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wfex;
wfex.Format.cbSize = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE);
wfex.Format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE;
wfex.Format.nChannels = 2;
wfex.Format.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
wfex.Format.wBitsPerSample = 16;
wfex.Format.nBlockAlign = wfex.Format.nChannels * wfex.Format.wBitsPerSample / 8;
wfex.Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfex.Format.nSamplesPerSec * wfex.Format.nBlockAlign;
wfex.Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = wfex.Format.wBitsPerSample;
wfex.SubFormat = KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM;
wfex.dwChannelMask = 0;

WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx = reinterpret_cast<WAVEFORMATEX*>(&wfex);
WAVEFORMATEX* pWfxout = nullptr;

hr = pAudioClient->IsFormatSupported(
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE,
    pwfx,
    &pWfxout
);

assert(hr == S_OK);

hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE,
    0,
    hnsRequestedDuration,
    0,
    pwfx,
    nullptr);

assert(hr == S_OK);
```

And both calls succeeds with `S_OK`.

**(1) Why is this happening?** This is especially troubling because in this case the `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` conceptually describes the same format as the `WAVEFORMATEX`. **(2) Should we just *not* use `WAVEFORMATEX` because it was deprecated?** I thought it was okay to use if it can indeed describe the format that you need (good ol' Stereo CD PCM in this case).